# org.apache.wicket.Component to be replaced with JSP

Tags: java, shiro, wicket-1.6

we are migrating a legacy front end application which was built on Apache Wicket (1.3.5) to jsp with spring-mvc. What can be the exact match for replacing org.apache.wicket.Component in my migration?

The reason for asking this question is, we need to design our application with role based look and feel / restrict the access for some pages/operations.

Points to be considered,
we have Apache shiro for authorization on every page. It will be better to have a generic class implementation where I can build the UI forms / pages / controls based on the role assigned to the user.

Appreciating your help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct replacement of any Wicket class to JSP. There are facilities in newer versions of Wicket to render components (instead of complete page) and consume such HTML snippets in your JSP code but 1.3.5 is too old.

I'd recommend you to just implement the functionality from scratch in idiomatic Spring MVC.